# Make <label> clickable in <li>

Tags: html, input, label

I have `<input type="radio"` which i need to make activated when i click on `<li>` element. I have `<label><li></li></label>`, `label` is used to activate `radio` here (it works). The problem is `<li>` visually gets separated from other `<li>`s. I tried making `<li><label></label></li>` but it makes `radio` activated only when text inside `<label>` is clicked. In other words, i need `<li><label></label><li>` to work even when i'm clicking not the insides of `<label></label>`. Here's the picture  of when it's `<label><li></li></label>` (ignore `radio`s, those are not the problem):

[image: screenshot of label and li inside]

This problem isn't about radio - I have shown radio on screenshot just to know if radio successfully activated by clicking on label or not. The problem is `<label><li></li></label>` has `<li>` inside but it's the `<label>` which should be inside `<li>`. If I do so (`label` inside `li`), then only "test-60" text is clickable and activates radio, not the whole `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="radio-button">test 60</label>
<input type="hidden" value="test-60" id="radio-button"/>
```

also, recommend making input in position absolute and top 0 and left 0

[Example](https://codepen.io/OmerCohen/pen/gOMJvVW)

Comment: This problem isn't about radio - I have shown radio on screenshot just to know if radio successfully activated by clicking on label or not. The problem is `<label><li></li></label>` has `<li>` inside but it's the `<label>` which should be inside `<li>`. If I do so (label inside li), then only "test-60" text is clickable and activates radio, not the whole `<li>`

Comment: all idea is the for property :)

Comment: I mean I wish I could use "for" on other tags, would be easier

Comment: to create a list you do not need ul and li tags.
just make under div the label right with CSS and you have a great list.